# CloudFront - Streaming distribution - ignores files not in root

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I've got a bunch of videos in a directory, in my S3 bucket.

dataBucket contains: **videos/18512/version1.flv** - also contains other versions in that directory

Now, when using RTMP streaming distribution via Cloudfront it will **only** work if the video files are in the root of the bucket. If in sub directories, as you see with my structure (which is necessary really), it will ignore/not find the files.

I can't see anything about this on Amazon support or googling, or indeed here. Any advice if this is *nature of the beast* or a setting/config issue?

Answer (score 1):

Was stuck on this issue myself, turns out for JW player you need to precede the path with the mp4: prefix.

So for your example the rtmp path to Cloud Front would be.

rtmp://xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:videos/18512/version1.flv

Figure you must have gotten past this due the age of the question.  But since this came up in my search for an answer, figured to leave it for others who might find it as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which player you are using. With JW player you set it like this:

'file': 'yourfolder/yourmovie.mp4',
’streamer’: ‘rtmp://xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/cfx/st’,

Full explanation how this works with JW player: http://www.miracletutorials.com/how-to-switch-from-low-resolution-video-to-hd-part-2/

Also, it is possible that your folder is private while you try to stream public.  Did you check that?

Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flowplayer and aws, you must supply the netConnectionUrl in plugins : rtmp - other streaming locations did not require you to do this.

```
playlist: [
         folder/flvItem //no longer has 'rtmp://somewhere.cloudfront.net/cfx/st', just the rest of the url
      ],
       plugins: {
           rtmp: {
               url: 'flowplayer.rtmp-3.1.3.swf'
               , netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://somewhere.cloudfront.net/cfx/st' //must supply now
           },
```